# HTTP Error 524 while crawling big websites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-3.5, urllib

I want to crawl a website with 786 pages. my code extracts data and save it to an excel file. when I run my program for 10 pages, it works fine but when I try to crawl whole 786 pages at one-time it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 32, in <module>
    crawl_names(i)
  File "app.py", line 16, in crawl_names
    html = urlopen(rq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 524: Origin Time-out
```

my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import xlwt


headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

def crawl_names(page):
    site = 'http://nex1music.ir/pages/' + str(page) + '/'
    rq = Request(site, headers=headers)
    html = urlopen(rq)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    musics = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "pctn"})

    names = []
    for m in musics:
        names.append(m.findChild().findAll("a", {"href": re.compile("http\:\/\/nex1music\.ir\/tag\/.+\/")})[-1].string)



    for i in range(len(names)):
        sheet1.write(i, page-1, names[i])



for i in range(1, 786):
    crawl_names(i)

book.save("data.xls")
```

How can I change my code in order to crawl whole 786 pages ? thank you.

Comment: You're probably being rate-limited. Add a `time.sleep()` call to insert a delay between each request.

Comment: @kindall I will check it. thanks